# Best practices for API hooks/callbacks?

Tags: web-services, api, callback, soa, webhooks

Lets say I have web applicatons/services:

- *API*
- Set of *Applications*

*API* is used for managing some resources (simple CRUD operations). Now what I need is to subscribe *Applications* for changes of different *API* resources. *Applications* would do some background work on a change.

---

I came up to idea of callbacks. So that *Applications* can **oauth**orise and post to the *API* a callback config.

I think that this config should look like this:

```
{
  'callback_url': 'http://3rdpartyservice.com/callback',
  'resources':    ['foo1', 'foo2'],
  'ref_data':     { 'token': 'abcd1234' }
}
```

- *resources* is array of the resources that 3rd party service is interested in
- *ref_data* is custom json for 3rd party usage (e.g. for auth)

This way on specified resource change the *API* would send a request to *callback_url*. This request would contain resource data, action(create/update/delete) and *ref_data*.

**The intention here is to make this generic enough to allow 3rd party clients configure such callbacks.**

---

So the question are:

1. Are there any best practices?
2. What about security potential issues?
3. Are there any real world examples on the web?

Tx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds very similar as [WebHooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook) or *Service Hooks*.

Check out the [Web Hooks on GitHub](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/), to get a good idea what they are and how they work. See also last alinea [Service Hooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#service-hooks), as it explains how github handles these WebHooks. This would be similar for your application. The [OAuth](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/) explains why and how it is done.

See also [Webhooks, REST and the Open Web](http://apiux.com/2013/09/12/webhooks/), from [API User Experience](http://apiux.com/).

There is even [RestHooks](http://resthooks.org/).

Answer (score 3):

The general solution to this requirement is usually called "publish/subscribe". There are dozens of solutions to this - google "publish subscribe REST" for some examples. You can also read "[Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/)".

They key challenge in this kind of solution is "real-time versus queue".

For instance, if you have an API with a million clients, who are all interested in the same event, you cannot guarantee that in real time you can reach all of those clients within whatever timeframe their application demands. You also have to worry about the network going away, or clients being temporarily down. In this case, you application might define an event queue, and clients look in that queue for events they're interested in. Once you go down that route, you're probably going to use some off-the-shelf software rather than building your own. [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) is a good open source implementation.

In your example, for instance, what happens if you cannot reach 3rdpartyservice.com? Or if http://3rdpartyservice.com/callback throws an error when posting an update to foo1, but not to foo2? Or if http://3rdpartyservice.com/ uses a different flavour of OAuth than you're used to? How do you guarantee http://3rdpartyservice.com/ that it's you who is posting an update, not a hacker?

Your choices really tend to come down to your non-functional requirements, rather than the functional ones - things like  uptime, guarantee of notification, guarantee of delivery, etc. are more important than the specifics of how you pass across the parameters, and whether it's "resource-based" or some other protocol.

Comment: ok thank you. These are the most interesting questions I wanted to get suggestions about:) My answers: 1-2) If 3rdparty doesn't respond with `200` within timeout then the event should be added to a queue. 3) Its not clear what you mean. Clients have to adopt to my OAuth scheme. 4) Thats what `ref_data` is responsible for. Are there better solutions for signing a request to guarantee that request is not from a hacker?

Comment: Those problems have all been solved already by frameworks like Camel - you may learn a lot by implementing them yourself, but if you just want to get working software, I'd just use an off the shelf thing.

Comment: Indeed _things like uptime, guarantee of notification, guarantee of delivery, etc. are important_ but have little to do with the solution chosen. These can be done by the _Camel_ as well as by _WebHooks_ or any other.

Comment: Hi @verhagen, I agree that it's possible to deliver those NFRs in lots of tools - just that queue-based solutions tend to focus on the NFRs I mention, where as "real-time" solutions (and I think WebHooks is real time) focus more on simplicity and "web friendliness".

Comment: @NevilleK indeed true, webhooks tent to sent a _ping_, to notify the subscriber(s) and then continues. Not standard checking who where responing with `200 - OK`, and tracking those who did not respond with _OK_, and then later sending that ping again. It is, in most cases, also not what you really want. What if a registered application is down, or did not un-subscribe, etc? But _yes_ this depends on the requirements!